# Parsing JSON on android from slim micro framework API

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, slim

How can I parse this type of JSON? All the information I could find is about data that includes a table name, but mine is without a table name, just with colums like this:

```
{
    "fk_Company": "1",
    "id_Article": "42614",
    "Reference": "M520345",
    "Designation": "FEUX AVD BOXER",
    "fk_ArtFam": null,
    "fk_ArtTyp": null,
    "fk_ArtCatg": null,
    "fk_Marque": null,
    "TxMarge": " 25 ",
    "PVTTC": " 14.479 ",
    "Vendable": null,
    "Etat": null,
    "DateCrt": null
}
```

`index.php` (api slim framework):

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
function connex(){
$serveur = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "bms1";

$conn = new mysqli($serveur, $username, $password, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
return $conn;
}
$app = new Slim\App();


$app->get('/articles', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $con=connex();
    $new="";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bms_op_article";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    foreach($result as $ligne){
        $new.=$response->withJson($ligne);  
    }
    return $new;    
});

$app->run();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am completely unclear as to what you're problem is.

However, your use of `$response->withJson()` is incorrect. `$response->withJson()` takes an associative array and returns a Response object with JSON in the body and so should be used like this:

```
$app->get('/test', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $dataToReturn = [
        "name": "Rob",
        "email": "rob@example.com",
    ];
    return $response->withJson($data);
});
```

It's unclear what `$result` in your code is. If it's an associative array, you can pass it to `withJson()` directly. If it isn't, then you need to iterate over it and set up an associative array.